# MVC3 System.Collections.Generic.List pass the wrong model item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone  I have checked my controller and view it seems there is no problem but I get System Colletion error.

Here is my controller

```
 public ViewResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.banner.ToList());
        }
```

Here is My View

```
{
@model IEnumerable<icerik.Models.banner>
}
```

And I get this error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[icerik.Models.banner]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[icerik.Models.contents]'.
```

Comment: did you build the project? Try build it again and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a partial in your main view:

```
@Html.Partial("SomePartial")
```

and this partial is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<contents>`:

```
@model IEnumerable<icerik.Models.contents>
```

So make sure that you are passing the correct model to this partial. If you do not specify anything to the Partial helper (as in my example) the main model will be passed to this partial.

So always specify the correct model:

```
@Html.Partial("SomePartial", SomeModelInstance)
```

Comment: I have no partial view in my view

Comment: What about partials in your Layout? Try searching for `IEnumerable<icerik.Models.contents>`. You must be having some view or partial which is strongly typed to this model and which is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much I have found my stronged type in my shared view :/